# Flutter: navigator shows wrong page on back button

Tags: flutter, dart

I made a function that goes to the next page base on a list that has the pages that it has to view.

```
todoPages = [1,2,3];


int indexOfList = 0;
    

returnPage(int number) {
  if (number == 1) {
    return Screen1();
  }
  if (number == 2) {
    return Screen2();
  }
  if (number == 3) {
    return Screen3();
  }
}



nextPage() {

   indexOfList = indexOfList == 3 ? 3 : IndexOfList + 1;

   Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => returnPage(todoPages[indexOfList])),
    );
}
```

This works, It goes from Screen1 to 2 and 3.

But if I go back, it keeps going back to screen 3 (I think it's because todoPages[indexOfList] keeps returning 3).

With Navigator.pop(context);

Is there a way that Flutter "Remembers" from which pages I come and not "recalculates it" before going back?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide the full code for the three screens

Comment: Just 3 stateful widgets with an appbar.

Comment: I would help you better with your problem if i see your implementation.